# Download website locally without Javascript using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to download a website as ***static***, I mean without JS, only HTML & CSS.

I've tried many approaches yet some issues still present regarding **CSS** and **Images**.

A snippet

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const {URL} = require('url');
const fse = require('fs-extra');
const path = require('path');


(async (urlToFetch) => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: true,
        slowMo: 100
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);

    page.on("request", request => {
      if (request.resourceType() === "script") {
        request.abort()
      } else {
        request.continue()
      }
    })
    page.on('response', async (response) => {
        const url = new URL(response.url());
        let filePath = path.resolve(`./output${url.pathname}`);
        if(path.extname(url.pathname).trim() === '') {
            filePath = `${filePath}/index.html`;
        }
        await fse.outputFile(filePath, await response.buffer());
        console.log(`File ${filePath} is written successfully`);
    });

    await page.goto(urlToFetch, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    })

    setTimeout(async () => {
        await browser.close();
    }, 60000 * 4)


})('https://stackoverflow.com/');
```

I've tried using

```
content = await page.content();
fs.writeFileSync('index.html', content, { encoding: 'utf-8' });
```

As well as, I download it using `CDPSession`.

I've tried it using [website-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/website-scraper)

So what is the best approach to come to a solution where I provide a website link, then It downloads it as static website.

Comment: Do you wish to try other solutions in Python or Java? Or do you only work with Javascript?

Comment: Stackoverflow has a very robust built-in anti-crawler/anti-scraper gateway. I do not think you can effectively bulk download pages by crawling, unless you can deal with CAPTCHA.

Comment: @justthink I've mentioned a tag which refers to javascript in the question

Comment: @justthink I am not dealing with `stackover flow` website, my question refers to many websites, so let's consider these websites have no anti-crawler

Comment: Why do you need to do that ?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what issues you had with `page.content()`? That is generally the best solution here.

Comment: Puppeteer is for automating interactivity with JS. It operates on dynamic content, not static content. If you just want to get static HTML from a site, why not download it with axios? If you don't want the script tags, you could remove them with jsdom. This should be far easier, faster and more robust than Puppeteer. If this proposal isn't what you want, please explain your use case a bit more specifically to motivate why you're using Puppeteer.

Comment: @crg I just need to get all html elements with their styles then apply some manipulation on it locally

Comment: @Benny It does not download associated external css and normal or lazy loaded images

Comment: @ggorlen I am using puppeteer to simulate human login then extracting the page, so do you recommend to use `axios` and `request` instead ?

Comment: @AbdulrahmanFalyoun - You are really trying to go beyond what puppeteer is intended for and will do.  For the reasons you mentioned, converting a dynamic website into static is not simple.  I don't know of a library that will do that.  Not sure if it will work for your use case, but you could try this: (1) take the code from `page.content()` and put it on a local web server so that your web browser is properly interpreting and loading the CSS/HTML, (2) specify new base so images like `src="img/pic.gif"` will load using a new `base`: `<base href="https://www.example.com/" target="_blank">`

Comment: @Benny I'll try this approach, I think it might be a bit tricky to correctly link images, css and other files, yet I hope it works, thanks

Comment: Pls don't use this to scam people

Answer (score 2):

Try using this https://www.npmjs.com/package/website-scraper

It will save the website into a local directory

Comment: I tried this lib, I need to login before then supply cookies, this library does not support or cookies are now working with it

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like wget or curl?

```sh
wget -p https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67559777/download-website-locally-without-javascript-using-puppeteer
```

Should do the trick

Comment: I need to access authorized link, I mean I have to provide cookies then crawl the website